# Возможно ли использование yandex api в серверном приложении?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Разрабатывается серверное приложение (расчёт стоимости доставки), которое на вход получает конечную точку доставки. На сервере необходимо определить дистанцию от склада до конечной точки (расчёт по координатам), и то, попадает ли конечная точка в какую либо зону доставки (полигон).
Вопроc в том, можно ли каким-то образом использовать api яндекса в серверном приложении?
Сам пишу приложение на NestJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы через сервер предназначены [API Маршрутизатора](https://yandex.ru/dev/routing/router) и [Матрица расстояний](https://yandex.ru/dev/routing/distance_matrix/). Они дадут и сам маршрут, и время с дистанцией маршрута.

Определение же зоны доставки у Яндекса реализовано только на фронте через интегрированный в [JavaScript API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones) [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.html).

Первые сервисы платные коммерческие. Если всё реализовать на стороне клиента на базе **[JS API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/)**, можно уложиться и в [бесплатные условия](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/).